# Boost.asio compilation problem: undefined reference to `__sync_add_and_fetch_8

Tags: boost, compiler-construction, boost-asio, mips, mips64

Hey guys,
This could be a noob question, but I really can't find any useful solution through Google.
I'm testing a hello world with boost.asio, the program is quite simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
    t.wait();
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I passed the compilation and run well on my **Intel Pentium PC (Ubuntu 10.10, gcc 4.4.5, Boost 1.46.0)**. The command line I used was

> g++ -o a a.cpp -I /Boost-Include-Path/ -L /Boost-lib-Path/ -lboost_system

But when I compile the same code on another machine(which is a big one, I'll explain it later), it can't pass the compilation and gives such errors:

---

> /tmp/ccOZxZBX.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::gcc_sync_fenced_block::gcc_sync_fenced_block()': a.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail21gcc_sync_fenced_blockC1Ev[boost::asio::detail::gcc_sync_fenced_block::gcc_sync_fenced_block()]+0x4c): undefined reference to`__sync_lock_test_and_set_4' /tmp/ccOZxZBX.o: In function `boost::detail::atomic_count::operator++()': a.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6detail12atomic_countppEv[boost::detail::atomic_count::operator++()]+0x30): undefined reference to`__sync_add_and_fetch_8' /tmp/ccOZxZBX.o: In function `boost::detail::atomic_count::operator--()': a.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6detail12atomic_countmmEv[boost::detail::atomic_count::operator--()]+0x30): undefined reference to`__sync_add_and_fetch_8' /tmp/ccOZxZBX.o: In function `boost::detail::atomic_count::operator long() const': a.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost6detail12atomic_countcvlEv[boost::detail::atomic_count::operator long() const]+0x30): undefined reference to`__sync_fetch_and_add_8'

---

The machine I used was a SiCortex SC5832,which use MIPS64 instruction set processors, OS is changed CentoOS. Gcc 4.2.3, Boost1.46.0. Is it possible that there are problems about the compatibility of the MIPS? I added -mips64 option, but it still give the same errors.
I know this environment could not be very usual, but I think some people who are using similar big machines may face the same problem.

Any help would be appreciated. By the way, I don't have sudo permission.

Thanks,
Tony

Comment: How are you building boost? From source using bjam?

Comment: Yes, I bootstrap --prefix=..--with-libraries=system,thread..,, then bjam install, did I miss anything?

Comment: not likely, it seems like an environment that boost does not normally build on. You should forward this question to the [boost-users](http://www.boost.org/community/groups.html#users) mailing list.

Comment: thanks, I already post the question on the mailling list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is a GCC built-in function, and it was introduced around GCC 4.2 (iirc) [see documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html).

According to the documentation it's not available on all target processors.

If you look at `boost/smart_ptr/detail/atomic_count.hpp` it looks like it would fall into the `#elif defined(BOOST_SP_HAS_SYNC)` block. i.e. `boost/smart_ptr/detail/atomic_count_sync.hpp`.

Support for this is determined in `boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_has_sync.hpp`. This header essentially assumes that GCC supports this on all platforms except for a few exceptions. You might want to insert MIPS as another exception here and submit a patch to boost.

You'll also see that one workaround is to define **BOOST_AC_USE_PTHREADS**. This will use a mutex around the atomic count, which probably is significantly less efficient, but at least it will work until you can figure out what atomic operations are supported on MIPS64.

Comment: OK, sounds like pretty complicated, I'm not really need BOOST, just need a network library, so you have any suggestion except for BOOST and ACE(I can't install it on SiCortex)?

Comment: @Tony Complicated supercomputer architectures often require non-trivial solutions. Welcome to supercomputing :-). Did you try @Arvid's suggestion of using the `BOOST_AC_USE_PTHREADS`? That seems like it would get you going, with somewhat of a performance hit.